# How could someone's account that is secured by MFA Yubikey be compromised?

Tags: multi-factor, yubikey, fido2

Let's say that I purchased a MFA Yubikey device to secure my accounts. If an attacker wanted to compromise my accounts that are secured with this YubiKey, would this be possible without having the actual device?

First let's assume the attacker has had no physical access to the device but has been able to compromise other devices that the user uses (PC, Phone, Tablet etc.).  Second, the attacker was able to gain physical access to said device for an unknown amount of time.

Comment: Not described:  Were any compromised devices compromised when / while the user was logged into any of the accounts?  Was the Yubikey plugged into any compromised devices while they were compromised?  Was the Yubikey one of the models that requires user interaction to authenticate?

Answer (score 1):

Just because you have a Yubikey doesn't mean you can't be phished. It's just much much harder. If you reflexively provide MFA codes whenever asked, even when it is unexpected or unsolicited, then it doesn't have a lot of value.

There have also been cases of back channel hacking where the MFA server itself was hacked, and everything relying on it was then vulnerable.

Answer (score 1):

You describe the worst-case scenario.  You are using an untrustworthy device to access sensitive information or significant resources using online services.

Yes, this is a bad idea.

Examples of why:

Attacker replaces your bank bookmarks / hijacks your browser session when you try to visit your bank.  The first attempt to log in is passed directly to the bank and is successful (for the attacker), but you are shown a failed login page.  You are redirected to your bank's actual login page, where you login successfully the second time.  Congratulations, your attacker is now logged into your bank at the same time.

Alternatively, you are done with Facebook for the day and log out (Really?  People log out of Facebook?  Ever?).  The attacker (controlling your computer) intercepts and prevents that logout, and continues on with your Facebook session in your stead.

Even barring those active attacks, the attacker can observe all of the information your account login was protecting as you view it.

All of that said, you are still better protected with hardware MFA than without.  Mitigations for the risks described above would be:

- Ensure session limits (auto-log-out (e.g. 60 minutes) after you log in, and after you are idle) are enabled for your sensitive sites (banks do this).
- Turn on alerting for sensitive operations (withdrawals,for example).
- Work to protect the computers you use for sensitive computing.  Simple stuff like antivirus and firewalls and good passwords.
- Check / review last-logged-in-time/date/location for your sensitive services, particularly if anything weird happens like you have to log in twice, or your session seems to have lasted past logging out.

Answer (score -1):

The attacker could steal cookies for the session while you are logged in. In case of physical access the attacker could extract keys from the device or potentially modify it. Attacks for extraction are expensive and could make it obvious (disassembly could be required) but they have been succesful in the past if the attacker is well-equipped.

Comment: Cookie stealing has multiple protections, so this is only relevant if the service does not have those protections (that might be worth including in your answer). The OP states that the attacker does not have access to the Yubikey device, so "extraction" is out of scope of the possible threats. The OP already says that endpoints are compromised, and you don't explain how device compromise can compromise the account.